# Asymptotic distribution of $\lambda_1$ under the $z$-measure for partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, rt.representation-theory

The following question about $z$-measures on Young diagrams came up in some ongoing work with [Ofir Gorodetsky](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~franco/). I recall the background and then state our question below in the box.

For parameters $z$ and $z'$, define a measure on $\lambda \vdash n$ with the weights
$$
M_{n,z,z'}(\lambda):= \frac{(\dim \lambda)^2}{n!\, (z z')_n} \prod_{\square \in \lambda} (z + c(\square))(z' + c(\square)).
$$
Here $\dim \lambda$ is the number of standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$, the product is over all squares $\square$ in the diagram of $\lambda$, and $c(\square) := \mathrm{column}(\square) - \mathrm{row}(\square)$ is the *content* of $\square$. $(t)_n := t (t+1)\cdots (t + n-1)$. Definitions of the terminology used here can be found in e.g. vol. II of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics. Kerov discovered the remarkable fact that these weights induce a probability measure:
$$
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} M_{n, z, z'}(\lambda) = 1.
$$
(At any rate they sum to $1$; they are a probability measure if all of them are non-negative.) Some of the proofs of this fact can be found for instance [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002135) or in section 8 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9804086).

Let $\lambda^{(z,z',n)}$ be a random partition of $n$ according to these weights. We are interested in the limiting distribution of $\lambda_1$ under these weights in the case that $z = z' = \alpha > 0$. For $c \in [0,1]$, define
$$
F_\alpha(c) := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\lambda_1^{(\alpha, \alpha, n)} \leq cn) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{\substack{\lambda \vdash n \\ \lambda_1 \leq cn}} M_{n,z,z'}(\lambda).
$$
This limit is known to exist (and in fact converges to the distribution of $\alpha_1$ of the Thoma complex under the spectral z-measure; see [this paper of Borodin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9804087.pdf)). There are a variety of formulas characterizing the spectral z-measure in that paper (e.g. Theorem 2.2.1 for correlation functions of the Thoma point process), but we are interested in *positivity* of $F_\alpha(c)$ and have not been successful in applying these formulas to this. More exactly, we are interested in the following question:

> **Question:** Is it true for each $\alpha \in (0,1)$, that $F_\alpha(c) > 0$ for all $c > 0$?

We are also interested in the behavior of $F_\alpha(c)$ when $\alpha > 1$ (we really understand matters completely only when $\alpha$ is a positive integer), and any information relevant would be interesting, but the question above is the one that is really pressing.

Below are some approximate graphs (generated from $M_{n,\alpha,\alpha}$ with $n=45$) of $F_\alpha(c)$ for $\alpha = .01, .1, .3, .5,$ and $.7$. The graph for $\alpha = .01$ is at the top and $\alpha = .7$ is on the bottom. $c$ of course is the horizontal axis.

[image: $F_\alpha(c)$]

(The apparent changes in convexity for $c$ near $1$ in the bottom two graphs are just a remnant of polynomial interpolation and should be ignored.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *positive* answer to Brad and mine's question is the main result of a recent paper of Olshanski, titled "The Topological Support of the z-Measures on the Thoma Simplex" ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10688-018-0240-5)). His proof is based on a previous work of [his](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/2010/6/1102/771199), as well as a recent paper of [Korotkikh](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07454).

Interestingly, this question has (conjecturally) a simple number-theoretical interpretation, in terms of the distribution of the $z$th divisor function in short intervals and in arithmetic progressions. See Conjecture 4 in [Brad and mine's preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06002).